# How to create CSV Excel file C#?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, export

I'm looking for a class for creating CSV Excel files.

Expected features:

- Extremely simple to use
- Escapes commas and quotes so excel handles them fine
- Exports date and datetimes in timezone-proof format

Do you know any class capable of this?

Comment: better to pose the question in the QUESTION part, and then post your own answer in the ANSWER part.  Be sure to add tags and keywords in the question to make it searchable.

Comment: IMPORTANT: you should also add quotes when there's CARRIAGE RETURNS in the "value".

Comment: Thanks @Chris, a suggestion if I may,  this code can throw a KeyNotFoundException, please see my answer.

Comment: Its best example...but how can i add two table in single file,means i have a one table of two rows and other table is 10 rows and both have unique column name.I want to add two rows table on top and after gap of two lines i want to add second table.

Answer (score 92):

Slightly different version I wrote using reflection for my needs. I had to export a list of objects to csv. In case someone wants to use it for future.

```
public class CsvExport<T> where T: class
    {
        public List<T> Objects;

        public CsvExport(List<T> objects)
        {
            Objects = objects;
        }

        public string Export()
        {
            return Export(true);
        }

        public string Export(bool includeHeaderLine)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //Get properties using reflection.
            IList<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            if (includeHeaderLine)
            {
                //add header line.
                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
                {
                    sb.Append(propertyInfo.Name).Append(",");
                }
                sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).AppendLine();
            }

            //add value for each property.
            foreach (T obj in Objects)
            {               
                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
                {
                    sb.Append(MakeValueCsvFriendly(propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null))).Append(",");
                }
                sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).AppendLine();
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        //export to a file.
        public void ExportToFile(string path)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path, Export());
        }

        //export as binary data.
        public byte[] ExportToBytes()
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Export());
        }

        //get the csv value for field.
        private string MakeValueCsvFriendly(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return "";
            if (value is Nullable && ((INullable)value).IsNull) return "";

            if (value is DateTime)
            {
                if (((DateTime)value).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0)
                    return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            }
            string output = value.ToString();

            if (output.Contains(",") || output.Contains("\""))
                output = '"' + output.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"';

            return output;

        }
    }
```

Usage sample : (updated per comment)

```
CsvExport<BusinessObject> csv= new CsvExport<BusinessObject>(GetBusinessObjectList());
Response.Write(csv.Export());
```

Comment: It was more like this: 
List<BusinessObject> x= new List<BusinessObject>(); CsvExport<BusinessObject> x = new CsvExport<BusinessObject>(MUsers);

Comment: Where did your INullable interface come from?

Comment: Its best example...but how can i add two table in single file,means i have a one table of two rows and other table is 10 rows and both have unique column name.I want to add two rows table on top and after gap of two lines i want to add second table.

Comment: I know the original post was from 2011, so I'm not sure if it was possible in the .NET version which was used back then. But why not remove the `public string Export()` method and change the other method to `public string Export(bool includeHeaderLiner = true)` (with a default parameter value). Again, I'm not sure if default parameters were available in 2011, but the current code just looks onorthodox to me.

Answer (score 19):

Please forgive me

But I think a public open-source repository is a better way to share code and make contributions, and corrections, and additions like "I fixed this, I fixed that"

**So I made a simple git-repository out of the topic-starter's code and all the additions:**

https://github.com/jitbit/CsvExport

I also added a couple of useful fixes myself. Everyone could add suggestions, fork it to contribute etc. etc. etc. Send me your forks so I merge them back into the repo.

PS. I posted all copyright notices for Chris. @Chris if you're against this idea - let me know, I'll kill it.

Answer (score 11):

Another good solution to read and write CSV-files is [filehelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) (open source).

Comment: NB: [Excel support is only for basic scenarios](http://www.filehelpers.net/mustread/): The current implemented Excel support is only for basic scenarios. If you need custom formatting, charts, etc. you must go for a custom code. It's strongly recommended to directly use the NPOI library

Answer (score 6):

How about using string.Join instead of all the foreach Loops?

Comment: String.Join only works on string[], whereas i'm using some of the features of List<string>.

Comment: `String.Join("," , List<string>)` works also.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone would like I converted this to an extension method on IEnumerable:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static string ExportAsCSV<T>(this IEnumerable<T> listToExport, bool includeHeaderLine, string delimeter)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        IList<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        if (includeHeaderLine)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
            {
                sb.Append(propertyInfo.Name).Append(",");
            }
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).AppendLine();
        }

        foreach (T obj in listToExport)
        {
            T localObject = obj;

            var line = String.Join(delimeter, propertyInfos.Select(x => SanitizeValuesForCSV(x.GetValue(localObject, null), delimeter)));

            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static string SanitizeValuesForCSV(object value, string delimeter)
    {
        string output;

        if (value == null) return "";

        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            output = ((DateTime)value).ToLongDateString();
        }
        else
        {
            output = value.ToString();                
        }

        if (output.Contains(delimeter) || output.Contains("\""))
            output = '"' + output.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"';

        output = output.Replace("\n", " ");
        output = output.Replace("\r", "");

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

great work on this class. Simple and easy to use. I modified the class to include a title in the first row of the export; figured I would share:

use:

```
CsvExport myExport = new CsvExport();
myExport.addTitle = String.Format("Name: {0},{1}", lastName, firstName));
```

class:

```
public class CsvExport
{
    List<string> fields = new List<string>();

    public string addTitle { get; set; } // string for the first row of the export

    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> currentRow
    {
        get
        {
            return rows[rows.Count - 1];
        }
    }

    public object this[string field]
    {
        set
        {
            if (!fields.Contains(field)) fields.Add(field);
            currentRow[field] = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddRow()
    {
        rows.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>());
    }

    string MakeValueCsvFriendly(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return "";
        if (value is Nullable && ((INullable)value).IsNull) return "";
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            if (((DateTime)value).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0)
                return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        }
        string output = value.ToString();
        if (output.Contains(",") || output.Contains("\""))
            output = '"' + output.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"';
        return output;

    }

    public string Export()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // if there is a title
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(addTitle))
        {
            // escape chars that would otherwise break the row / export
            char[] csvTokens = new[] { '\"', ',', '\n', '\r' };

            if (addTitle.IndexOfAny(csvTokens) >= 0)
            {
                addTitle = "\"" + addTitle.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
            }
            sb.Append(addTitle).Append(",");
            sb.AppendLine();
        }


        // The header
        foreach (string field in fields)
        sb.Append(field).Append(",");
        sb.AppendLine();

        // The rows
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> row in rows)
        {
            foreach (string field in fields)
                sb.Append(MakeValueCsvFriendly(row[field])).Append(",");
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public void ExportToFile(string path)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, Export());
    }

    public byte[] ExportToBytes()
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Export());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

there's an open-source library for CSV which you can get using nuget: http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Answer (score 3):

I added ExportToStream so the csv didn't have to save to the hard drive first.

```
public Stream ExportToStream()
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(Export(true));
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've added

```
public void ExportToFile(string path, DataTable tabela)
{

     DataColumnCollection colunas = tabela.Columns;

     foreach (DataRow linha in tabela.Rows)
     {

           this.AddRow();

           foreach (DataColumn coluna in colunas)

           {

               this[coluna.ColumnName] = linha[coluna];

           }

      }
      this.ExportToFile(path);

}
```

Previous code does not work with old .NET versions. For 3.5 version of framework use this other version:

```
        public void ExportToFile(string path)
    {
        bool abort = false;
        bool exists = false;
        do
        {
            exists = File.Exists(path);
            if (!exists)
            {
                if( !Convert.ToBoolean( File.CreateText(path) ) )
                        abort = true;
            }
        } while (!exists || abort);

        if (!abort)
        {
            //File.OpenWrite(path);
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                w.WriteLine("hello");
            }

        }

        //File.WriteAllText(path, Export());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for that!
I modified the class to:

- use a variable delimiter, instead of hardcoded in code
- replacing all
  newLines (\n \r \n\r) in `MakeValueCsvFriendly`

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class CsvExport
    {

        public char delim = ';';
        /// <summary>
        /// To keep the ordered list of column names
        /// </summary>
        List<string> fields = new List<string>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The list of rows
        /// </summary>
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The current row
        /// </summary>
        Dictionary<string, object> currentRow { get { return rows[rows.Count - 1]; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set a value on this column
        /// </summary>
        public object this[string field]
        {
            set
            {
                // Keep track of the field names, because the dictionary loses the ordering
                if (!fields.Contains(field)) fields.Add(field);
                currentRow[field] = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call this before setting any fields on a row
        /// </summary>
        public void AddRow()
        {
            rows.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a value to how it should output in a csv file
        /// If it has a comma, it needs surrounding with double quotes
        /// Eg Sydney, Australia -> "Sydney, Australia"
        /// Also if it contains any double quotes ("), then they need to be replaced with quad quotes[sic] ("")
        /// Eg "Dangerous Dan" McGrew -> """Dangerous Dan"" McGrew"
        /// </summary>
        string MakeValueCsvFriendly(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return "";
            if (value is INullable && ((INullable)value).IsNull) return "";
            if (value is DateTime)
            {
                if (((DateTime)value).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0)
                    return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            }
            string output = value.ToString();
            if (output.Contains(delim) || output.Contains("\""))
                output = '"' + output.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"';
            if (Regex.IsMatch(output,  @"(?:\r\n|\n|\r)"))
                output = string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(output, @"(?:\r\n|\n|\r)"));
            return output;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Output all rows as a CSV returning a string
        /// </summary>
        public string Export()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // The header
            foreach (string field in fields)
                sb.Append(field).Append(delim);
            sb.AppendLine();

            // The rows
            foreach (Dictionary<string, object> row in rows)
            {
                foreach (string field in fields)
                    sb.Append(MakeValueCsvFriendly(row[field])).Append(delim);
                sb.AppendLine();
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Exports to a file
        /// </summary>
        public void ExportToFile(string path)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path, Export());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Exports as raw UTF8 bytes
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] ExportToBytes()
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Export());

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ADO to do this: http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2003/10/01/29964.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The original class have a problem, and that is if you want to add a new column, you will receive KeyNotFoundException on Export method. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var export = new CsvExport();

    export.AddRow();
    export["Region"] = "New York, USA";
    export["Sales"] = 100000;
    export["Date Opened"] = new DateTime(2003, 12, 31);

    export.AddRow();
    export["Region"] = "Sydney \"in\" Australia";
    export["Sales"] = 50000;
    export["Date Opened"] = new DateTime(2005, 1, 1, 9, 30, 0);
    export["Balance"] = 3.45f;  //Exception is throwed for this new column

    export.ExportToFile("Somefile.csv");
}
```

To solve this, and using the @KeyboardCowboy idea of ​​using reflection, I modified the code to allow add rows that do not have the same columns. You can use instances of anonymous classes. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var export = new CsvExporter();

    export.AddRow(new {A = 12, B = "Empty"});
    export.AddRow(new {A = 34.5f, D = false});

    export.ExportToFile("File.csv");
}
```

You can download the source code here [CsvExporter](https://gist.github.com/josephrodriguez/48b5f507b754c5211005). Feel free to use and modify.

Now, if all rows you want to write are of the same class, I created the generic class [CsvWriter.cs](https://gist.github.com/josephrodriguez/11b676f166211f5927df), which has a better performance RAM usage and ideal for writing large files.Plus it lets you add formatters to the data type you want. An example of use:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var writer = new CsvWriter<Person>("Persons.csv");

        writer.AddFormatter<DateTime>(d => d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

        writer.WriteHeaders();
        writer.WriteRows(GetPersons());

        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons()
    {
        yield return new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Jhon", 
                LastName = "Doe", 
                Sex = 'M'
            };

        yield return new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Jhane", 
                LastName = "Doe",
                Sex = 'F',
                BirthDate = DateTime.Now
            };
        }
    }


    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public char Sex  { get; set; }

        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need only 1 function to do this.
Only you have to do is to make a folder in your solution explorer and store the csv file there and then export that file to the user.

As in my case I have a folder downloads. First I export all my content to that directory and then exporting it to the user. For response.end handling, I used the ThreadAbortException. So it is a 100% genuine and working function in my solution.

```
protected void lnkExport_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string filename = strFileName = "Export.csv";

    DataTable dt = obj.GetData();  

// call the content and load it into the datatable

    strFileName = Server.MapPath("Downloads") + "\\" + strFileName;

// creating a file in the downloads folder in your solution explorer

    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(strFileName);

// using the built in class textwriter for writing your content in the exporting file

    string strData = "Username,Password,City";

// above line is the header for your exported file. So add headings for your coloumns in excel(.csv) file and seperate them with ","

    strData += Environment.NewLine;

// setting the environment to the new line

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
       strData += dr["Username"].ToString() + "," + dr["Password"].ToString() + "," +      dr["City"].ToString();
       strData += Environment.NewLine;
    }

// everytime when loop execute, it adds a line into the file
    tw.Write(strData);

// writing the contents in file
    tw.Close();

// closing the file
    Response.Redirect("Downloads/" + filename);

// exporting the file to the user as a popup to save as....
}
```