# C# Model Object For a Report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am generating a report from a stored proc that outputs a DataTable in the following format:

```
id    |    date    | value
--------------------------
0     |   5/18/11  | 10
0     |   5/19/11  | 13
0     |   5/20/11  | 7
0     |   5/21/11  | 1
1     |   5/18/11  | 9
1     |   5/19/11  | 34
1     |   5/20/11  | 5
1     |   5/21/11  | 6
```

where the id corresponds to an employee's id number.

I don't like dealing with raw DataTables throughout my code, but I don't know the best way to represent such information most effectively in some sort of model object in C#. How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make a class...

```
public class ReportModel 
{
  public int ID {get; private set;}
  public DateTime Date {get; private set;}
  public int Value {get; private set;}

  private ReportModel() {}

  public static ReportModel FromDataRow(DataRow dataRow)
  {
       return new ReportModel
       {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["id"]),
            Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dataRow["date"]),
            Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["value"])
       };
  } 

  public static List<ReportModel> FromDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
  {
       var list = new List<ReportModel>();

       foreach(var row in dataTable.Rows)
       {
            list.Add(ReportModel.FromDataRow(row);
       }

       return list;
  }
}
```

You can also use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to encapsulate the mapping from DataRow to ReportModel.

Comment: but this doesn't take into account the grouping of id's somehow to make it easier to work with. What I am wondering is how do people typically model such a class with C#?

Comment: You could use a Dictionary object for this...the key in the dictionary would be the ID and the Value in the dictionary could be a custom type that has two properties (date and value).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread, [How to create CSV Excel file C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422212/simple-c-csv-excel-export-class)