# how to export hierarchy to excel?

Tags: c#, excel, export, hierarchy

I am trying to use an Excel library like npoi, epplus, or closedxml to export a hierarchy  like the one here in this telerik example:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/export/exporthierarchicalgrid/defaultcs.aspx

Can someone please point me in the direction of some code examples to help me get started? I'm new to this. Would merge cells be used?

thanks!

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-HA010095247.aspx

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't see how that is helpful

Comment: You didn't seem to be aware of that functionality in Excel, else I would have expected you to mention it in your question, instead of pointing to the Telerik example.  I was pointing it out so you'd be able to find a library or approach which supported creating an output with grouped rows.

Comment: what I asked for in my question was how to use c# with a library to code a hierarchical result similar to the telerik export. I fail to see how that link helps me achieve that?

Comment: Then perhaps you could be more specific.  What exactly are you looking for: output like the "export to excel" on that page prduces, or collapsible rows like the html version? It's unclear from your question.

Comment: Once you have your hierachy of data then save it to an Excel sheet, here is some sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422212/simple-c-sharp-csv-excel-export-class

Comment: jeremy, thanks, but once again I don't see how that link helps me export similar to the telerik link....

Comment: someone at stackoverflow must have deleted my comment. I think my response was fitting as @TimWilliams tried to blame me for the fact that he did not pay attention to my question...everything is clear. that is not acceptable.