# How to save csv to memory and then ftp?

Tags: c#, csv, ftp, export

I am currently creating a CSV file and then I ftp that file.
This is working fine. However, I dont want to save the csv file, i want to create it to memory and then ftp it.

This is my current code:

```
private void Csv()
    {             
        CsvExport eftExport = new CsvExport();
        eftExport.AddRow();
        eftExport["customer_reference"] = "Ref";           
        eftExport["landline"] = "01234567890";
        string url = "C:/Content/Cms/DD/";
        string fileName = "file.csv";
        eftExport.ExportToFile(url + fileName);
        this.FtpFile(url, fileName);
    }

    private void FtpFile(string url, string fileName)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://url.co.uk/" + fileName);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("Administrator", "pass");

        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(url + fileName);
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();                       
    }
```

but in stead of doing eftExport.ExportToFile(url + fileName); i dont want it to save to machine??

Comment: Does CvsExport support writing to a stream?

Comment: i got it from ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422212/simple-c-sharp-csv-excel-export-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to but it into a byte array:

```
byte[] buffer = eftExport.ExportToBytes();
```

Now:

```
requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ExportToBytes()` function of your `CsvExport` class.

Then change your `FtpFile()` to accept a byte array and remove the stream reader

you should end up with quite a bit less code :)

Answer (score 0):

If your `CsvExport` type has an `ExportToStream` or similar simply use that create the stream that you subsequently write to the `requestStream`.