# Is it possible to create a excel or csv from a windows phone application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have DataContext in my windows phone application.

I want to generate a excel spreadsheet or csv file from the dataset.

Is it possible to create a csv or excel spreadsheet from the Windows Phone application ?

Comment: pretty much anything is possible; it's software.

Comment: @MitchWheat yep. But how to make it possible? that's the challenge here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSV file is simply a text file with fields separated by commas. They can store arbitrary data. You can either use a library to catch edge cases or simply write your values into a text file separated by commas if you want something quick and dirty.

A typical CSV file would look like this:

```
"Name","Age","Gender"
"Jenny",21,"Female"
"Bloggs, Fred",25,"Male"
```

Note, that strings are often stored in double-quotes and this is to help with things like "Bloggs, Fred" that contains a comma. This is where using a library comes in handy but you can hand crank yourself if you want.

Re Excel - assuming your CSV was well formed it would open it just fine. That doesn't mean it is an Excel file but just a file that Excel understands. Writing Excel files (depending on version of Excel) is more complicated but possible.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much. So I can create the txt file with comma, and should it with .csv extension. Is it right ?

Comment: For a fairly easy to use example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422212/simple-c-sharp-csv-excel-export-class or for an all singing all dancing http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/685310/Simple-and-fast-CSV-library-in-Csharp and of course MANY, MANY other libraries out there.

Comment: great that's for win-forms or wpf. any tutorial for windows phone for creating excel spreadsheets ?

Comment: Phone is exactly the same, don't worry what the examples are written in. You just write to a file (i.e. `TextWriter`) and write lines using commas to separate your fields. You don't need any special software to do it and phone is no different.