# Create and export csv file in console app C# without save on server

Tags: c#, csv, console-application

I am currently working on a console application which will retrieve information in a database to insert them into another database. I would like that once all data saved the application automatically generates and downloads a csv file on the user's computer. But without saving the file on the server.

Is this possible or do I have to create a temporary file?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: What server?  You said this was a console application.  A CSV file is just a string like any other, you can write it wherever you like.  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: Does this help, Space? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422212/how-to-create-csv-excel-file-c

Comment: FileStream filestream = new FileStream("loopdata.csv", FileMode.Create);
var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
Console.SetError(streamwriter);

Answer (score 1):

If the console application is running on the users PC simply saving the file like you would normally would save it to the PC the console app is running on:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Wherever\WriteText.csv", text);
```