# C# Equivalent of VBA Transfertext Function

Tags: c#, vba

I have been asked to rewrite a VBA tool into a C# application, but came across a line of code that I am not sure how to do the same thing in C# as it is done in VBA.

What would be the C# equivalent of the DoCMD.TransferText command to export data to a tab delimited file?

Here is the code currently being used in VBA:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "TEMP_Tracker Export Specification", "TEMP_Tracker", "\\BulkInsert\UtilityNotes.txt", True
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: The answer is not a one-liner.  It will likely involve creating a text file and writing the output line by line to it.  What's the definition of your output template `TEMP_Tracker Export Specification`?

Comment: How are you accessing your tables (like `TEMP_Tracker`) in your C# solution?  Are you pulling them into `DataSet`s?

Comment: Here is an entire article on this: (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a12e3b6e-3c8c-41a2-a210-7c53a5e5734c/docmdtransfertext-performance?forum=accessdev)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's nothing built-in.

The .NET Framework contains a class for **reading** delimiter-separated text files ([`TextFieldParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser), it's in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace but works with C# as well), but there's nothing built-in for **writing** them.

Your best bet would be to look for a CSV export library for .NET, or just write the code yourself: If the values you want to write are free of field and line delimiter characters, it's no more than a simple loop through your data source, adding the values to a `StringBuilder` and then writing it with `File.WriteAllText`. There are various sample implementations here on StackOverflow, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2422212/87698).